# SPIRV-cross get vertex layout info for Vulkan

Tags: c++, glsl, vulkan, spir-v

I need to reflect glsl shader and get vertex layout to automatically create VkPipelineVertexInputStateCreateInfo. I have done it that way:

```
spirv_cross::Compiler compiler(src);
spirv_cross::ShaderResources resources = compiler.get_shader_resources();

// only for vertex stage
for (const auto& resource : resources.stage_inputs)
{
    uint32_t location = compiler.get_decoration(resource.id, spv::DecorationLocation);
    auto type = compiler.get_type(resource.type_id);
}
// After calculate offsets and stride
```

Everything worked fine, until I wrote shader that does not use some vertex attributes. Vertex inputs look like this:

```
layout(location = 0) in vec3 a_Position;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 a_TexCoords;
layout(location = 2) in vec3 a_Normal;
layout(location = 3) in vec3 a_Tangent;
layout(location = 4) in vec3 a_Bitangent;
layout(location = 5) in ivec4 a_BoneIDs;
layout(location = 6) in vec4 a_Weights;
```

This shader uses only `a_Position, a_BoneIDs, a_Weights`. SPIRV-cross optimizes out other attributes and give only those 3. And now I cant calculate offsets for each attribute and cant get stride for whole vertex. I tried to get offset this way: `uint32 offset = compiler.get_decoration(resource.id, spv::DecorationOffset)`, but it always give me zero.
Even if I had offset for each attribute I would not be able to build a stride, because I cant get last attribute also.

So is there a way to get enough information from spirv-cross?

Comment: Vertex strides are not normally related to shader layout anyway. E.g. for Normal you would normally want to store that as something more compact, e.g. RGB10A2, as storing it as full floats is a waste of bandwidth. You're going to need some supplemental information from somewhere, that isn't the compiler, as the compiler doesn't know the in-memory type and precision.

Comment: I think you are right, I would need to manually set vertex layout for pipeline. Just started working with spirv and got inspiration to automate everything I could and could not)